# I want to paint an already made texture

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I want to edit a texture that I already made using Blender's texture painting, but I can't figure out how I do that. [image]

Comment: Connect the uv mapped image texture to your material first, possibly in the node editor, so that it shows up as a texture paint slot. It looks like right now the image in the UV Image Editor is not present in your material.